# My Timelock contract won't set a release time under 100000000000

Tags: solidity, remix, timelock

Newbie here. Really excited to be joining the community.

I've been trying to compile a basic timelock contract. I've finally managed to deploy it but I can only set the release time to 100000000000000 seconds. Anything under that I get this error message. [image]

I've tried varius networks, including Mainnet and i still get the same error message.

I also tried altering the block.timestamp in the construtor to +1 and -1 to see if that would help... No joy.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

PS I'm using remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./SafeERC20.sol";

/**
 * @dev A token holder contract that will allow a beneficiary to extract the
 * tokens after a given release time.
 *
 * Useful for simple vesting schedules like "advisors get all of their tokens
 * after 1 year".
 */
contract TokenTimelock {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    // ERC20 basic token contract being held
    IERC20 immutable private _token;

    // beneficiary of tokens after they are released
    address immutable private _beneficiary;

    // timestamp when token release is enabled
    uint256 immutable private _releaseTime;

    constructor (IERC20 token_, address beneficiary_, uint256 releaseTime_) {
        // solhint-disable-next-line not-rely-on-time
        require(releaseTime_ > block.timestamp, "TokenTimelock: release time is before current time");
        _token = token_;
        _beneficiary = beneficiary_;
        _releaseTime = releaseTime_;
    }

    /**
     * @return the token being held.
     */
    function token() public view virtual returns (IERC20) {
        return _token;
    }

    /**
     * @return the beneficiary of the tokens.
     */
    function beneficiary() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _beneficiary;
    }

    /**
     * @return the time when the tokens are released.
     */
    function releaseTime() public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _releaseTime;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Transfers tokens held by timelock to beneficiary.
     */
    function release() public virtual {
        // solhint-disable-next-line not-rely-on-time
        require(block.timestamp >= releaseTime(), "TokenTimelock: current time is before release time");

        uint256 amount = token().balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amount > 0, "TokenTimelock: no tokens to release");

        token().safeTransfer(beneficiary(), amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Solidity Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties) `block.timestamp` returns the timestamp of current block in seconds since the epoch. That means how many seconds passed since January 1, 1970.

So, if you want to release your token after 1 years from now, you have to add 1 year to the current timestamp and pass that value.

You can manually add `31556926 * YEARS` seconds to the today's timestamp, or you can use a app to make it.

For your error, I think this error happens because `100000000000000` seconds is approximately **3 million years**, and that's a **HUGE** number.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. Really appreciate it :)